# AcitivityMainBinding is not showing in my MainActivity.kt. How do I resolve this?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

We're doing a project for our research subject and our project is creating an android application. I'm currently trying to bind my activity_main.xml to my MainActivity.kt but the ActivityMainBinding is not showing up. How do I fix this issue?

Here are my codes:

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.googlemappspsssps

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration.getInstance
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory
import org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding //this shows as "Unresolved reference"
    private val REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private lateinit var map : MapView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this))
    }
    class OsmdroidMap : Activity() {
        private var mMapView: MapView? = null
        private var mMapController: MapController? = null
        public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            mMapView = findViewById<View>(R.id.map) as MapView
            mMapView!!.setScrollableAreaLimitDouble(BoundingBox(14.785336, 121.135023, 14.347804, 120.791703))
            mMapView!!.setMaxZoomLevel(20.0)
            mMapView!!.setMinZoomLevel(12.0)
            mMapView!!.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(false)
            mMapView!!.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false)
            mMapView!!.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE)
            mMapView!!.setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
            mMapController = mMapView!!.controller as MapController
            val gPt = GeoPoint(14.6503, 121.0405)
            mMapController!!.setCenter(gPt)
            mMapController!!.setZoom(18)
        }

        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this))
//        map.onResume(); //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
//        map.onPause();  //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/activity_body"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.googlemappspsssps'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.googlemappspsssps"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.14'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.14'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.14'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.36'
    implementation files('libs/osmdroid-android-6.1.14-javadoc.jar')

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I already set viewBinding true and dataBinding true. Tried renaming the xml file and tried closing Android studio and opening it again. I just started using Kotlin and Android Studio so I don't really have much experience yet with this.

Comment: Everything seems good. Try to invalidate cache and restart.